# android ViewSwitcher screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, viewswitcher

I have a `ViewSwitche`r in a `FragmentActivity` with in 2 layout files, one for each orientation. The `ViewSwitcher` is controlled by a `radio group`.

When I rotate the screen, everything behaves as I'd expect, the correct layout file is used to render the screen.

However, The radio group's `onCheckedChanged` event **is fired when the screen rotates**.
 The listener for that looks like this (created in `onCreate`):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //snip
        radios.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int index) {

            viewSwitcher.showNext();
        }
        });
 }
```

How can I call **viewSwitcher.showNext()** in the `listener` without having it fire when the screen is rotated?

Answer (score 0):

well, I sorta found a hacky solution, but I'm hoping there's a better one out there.

```
    private boolean wasRotatedHack;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        wasRotatedHack = false;
    } else {
        wasRotatedHack = true;
    }

    tabRadios.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int index) {

            if (!wasRotatedHack) {
                viewSwitcher.showNext();
            } else {
                wasRotatedHack = false;
            }
        }
    });

    startInspectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InspectionActivity.class));
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: just tested this a bit more, it gets messed up when you turn the screen off and come back on.  there must be a cleaner way...